# System.ArgumentException: 'Value BIGNUMERIC is undefined in BigQueryDbType

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

in GCP BigQuery id is BIGNUMERIC data,ora is string.

if not use id all work fine.

CODE:
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;

```
        var jsonPath = "acount.json";
        var projectId = "Projectname";
        var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonPath);
        var client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId, credentials);


        string query = @"
        SELECT *
        FROM `Temp.test`
        LIMIT 100";
        BigQueryJob job = client.CreateQueryJob(
            sql: query,
            parameters: null,
            options: new QueryOptions { UseQueryCache = false });
        // Wait for the job to complete.
        job = job.PollUntilCompleted().ThrowOnAnyError();
        // Display the results



        foreach (BigQueryRow row in client.GetQueryResults(job.Reference))
        {

            richTextBox1.Text += row["id"] + " | " + row["storeno"] + " | " + row["data"] +"\n";
        }
```

receive this error :

System.ArgumentException: 'Value BIGNUMERIC is undefined in BigQueryDbType
Parameter name: name'

Answer (score 0):

This is the error returned when the version of the Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 package doesn't support the data type being used.

The `BIGNUMERIC` type support was implemented just recently. It's not currently in a stable package, but I would urge you to test version 2.4.0-beta01 which includes support.

We hope to release a stable version (which will be 2.4.0) fairly soon. (Please file any issues you encounter [in our GitHub repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet) - hopefully it'll just work for you though.)

Comment: 0


the issue is in v2.3.0 ok solved in Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 -Version 2.4.0-beta01 from nuget console type " Install-Package Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 -Version 2.4.0-beta01" thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like what was mentioned before you can update to version 2.4.0-beta01.
If you cant update or don't want to update, for the BIGNUMERIC value instead of using row["Name"] you can use row.RawRow.F[ColNumber].V